# regex is not filtering text

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clean(e){
    var textfield = document.getElementById(e);
    var regex = /[^a-z 0-9]/gi;

    textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "");
}
</script>
<textarea id="ta" name="ta" onkeyup="clean('ta')" onkeydown="clean('ta')"></textarea>
```

as you can see that my code filter all the alphabet character and i expected to do this in real time but this code is not working. Please help me to sort out this problem.

[Fiddle represtation](http://jsfiddle.net/ux96B/)

Comment: Seems to work fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/NCL4s/

Comment: what do you exactly want to do ?

Comment: what do you want to keep?

Comment: i exactly want to remove all alphabet

Comment: Do you want a number? If you only want number, removing alphabet will not guarantee number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all alphabets (`A-Za-z`) with this:

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/ux96B/1/)

```
function clean(e) {
    var textfield = document.getElementById(e);
    var regex = /[a-z]/gi;    // all alphabet characters ignorecase
    textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

And you need to keep your JavaScript code in `<script>` tag, in the html, because when it by the time it reaches `onclick="clean('ta')"`, it hasn't yet reached the declaration of the function `clean` and hence throws a `ReferenceError` (which you see in the console (`F12`))

Comment: i think thisis what he wants, i was about to flag the question

Answer (score 0):

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xk8S/)**</kbd>

What can i do?

- Modify your existing regular expression to update this `/[a-zA-Z]/gi` to ignore both uppercase and lowercase alphabetically character.
- Here I can <kbd>[**validate**](http://regex101.com/r/xG8cM7)</kbd> your regular expression

---

#### HTML

```
<textarea id="ta" name="ta" onkeyup="clean('ta')" onkeydown="clean('ta')"></textarea>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function clean(e) {
    var textfield = document.getElementById(e);
    var regex = /[a-zA-Z]/gi;
    textfield.value = textfield.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

Hope this help you!